# Using r.neighbors on borders

Tags: grass-gis, borders, nodata

I have a raster file with pixel size 30 x 30. At the upper border there is half row with "no data" pixels. I want to use the mode function to replace them. I have only thought r.neighbors (from grass) with a moving window of 2x2 (just to take the values of the previous row). I haven't try this for filling areas on borders so my question, is it safe to use this function for borders where I have only one row as neighbors? (values are categorical of land cover)

Comment: "Safe" depends on what your subsequent analyses will be.  You are proposing a method of *data imputation*; whether it will bias subsequent results depends on why those data are missing and on the nature of the calculations.  Usually, a better cure for such boundary problems is to begin with a slightly larger grid extent (in all directions) in your raw data, anticipating that subsequent neighborhood operations will eliminate a few layers of boundary pixels by the end.

Comment: What about http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.grow.html ?

Comment: I agree with you whuber. After reading and some experiments I think the use of a larger extent is the best option. Now I want to explore the VIM package from R (for Imputation of Missing Values).